# mysql - How do we get the sum of the values on two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables

```
table: a
---------------------
id    amount  status
---------------------
4031  3000    1
4032  4000    1
4033  5000    1
4034  6000    1
4035  7000    1
4036  8000    0
```

```
table: s
--------------
id a_id  b_id 
--------------
1  4031  20
2  4031  21
3  4032  23
4  4032  24
5  4033  25
6  4033  26
7  4034  21
8  4034  20
9  4035  25
10 4035  29
11 4036  21
12 4036  20
```

How do we get the sum of the a.amount where have ( b_id = 20 AND b_id = 21) AND a.status = 1?

The answer should be 9000.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't see how the answer should be 9000.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM (
JOIN s ON a.id = s.id
WHERE STATUS =1
AND (b_id = 20 OR b_id = 21) GROUP BY a.id
) AS amounts
```

total : 9000

In the case you can add several times the same amount, I guess this should work without join:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total 
FROM `a`, `s` 
WHERE a_id = a.id AND (b_id = 20 OR b_id = 21) AND status = 1
```

total : 18000

Comment: Thumbs up @Moose.

Comment: i want table b have b_id = 20 AND b_id = 21

Comment: Right, it did not work - but edited, it should. ( how can b_id be two values at the same time? )

Comment: :D I know @cdaiga - you found first - just another syntax, but I don't know what's faster

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer using a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(a.amount)
FROM a
WHERE a.status=1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM s
              WHERE s.a_id=a.id AND s.b_id in (20,21));
```

There is no need to group the data as we want the global sum of the amounts selected.

Comment: See @Moose's anwer with JOIN. He gave a perfect explanation why you would need a join, but the query is quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sum(a.amount)
from a 
join b on a.id = b.a_id 
where b.b_id IN ( 20, 21 ) and a.status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(a.amount)
FROM a
WHERE a.status=1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM s
              WHERE s.a_id=a.id AND s.b_id=20) AND 
              EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM s
              WHERE s.a_id=a.id AND s.b_id=21) ;
```

Comment: You should use code formatting Hamed :) - Use the {} button